# Debug Inspection of Roo generated Java bean methods in STS

Tags: spring-roo, spring-tool-suite

When debugging in STS and I inspect a roo generated java bean method (for example entity.getValue() I receive the error "The method getValue() is undefined for the type Entity" (where entity is an instance of Entity). Control clicking on the getValue() method correctly shows the .aj file generated by Roo. Is there anything that needs to be configured to allow for debugging these methods?

I have tried STS 3.7.3 and 3.8.3 running Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE On Mac

Comment: could you provide more info about your Spring Roo version and the STS version you are using? Regards

Comment: I added the version information the the question above

Answer (score 0):

Usually, is not necessary to apply any changes in the generated project or STS to be able to debug the `.aj` files from STS.

However, sometimes is necessary to clean the project using the `Project > Clean...` action from the STS menu before to execute the application. That should happens if you have the `Build Automatically` option disabled.

After that, you should be able to debug the methods inside the `.aj` files.

Hope it helps,